# Exclude first 20 characters from findstr output

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I'm making a movie organizer for myself in batch, so I can easily manage my movies.
The main idea of the program is simple, I add movies to my library (which is a txt file) using the program, then I can view the details of the movies and watch the movies through the program. I've done basically everything, but I still have 1 problem.

As I said before, the movies added to the library are saved in a text file as follows:

```
Name: Test1
Year: Test1
Desc: Test1
MovieNumber1 Path: C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Movie1.mp4
----------------------------------------------------------------
Name: Test2
Year: Test2
Desc: Test2
MovieNumber2 Path: C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Movie2.mp4
----------------------------------------------------------------
Name: Test3
Year: Test3
Desc: Test3
MovieNumber3 Path: C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Movie3.mp4
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

To watch the movie, the user needs to insert the number of the movie, which is right next to the path (I know it's not the best idea, but it does the job).

I want to get the path and put it in a variable, so I can use that variable to play the movie in a media player through the batch file.

I wrote the following to do this job, but I still have one thing I don't know how to do:

```
set /p moviechoice=Select Movie


FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`findstr "MovieNumber%moviechoice%" Movies.txt`) DO (
SET selectedmovie=%%F
)

echo You selected %selectedmovie% 
PAUSE
```

Basically, the moviechoice variable lets the program know which movie to open. The input should be a number such as 2 if the user wants to view movie number 2.

I'm using the findstr command to look for "MovieNumber" followed by the input of the user in the last variable. So if the user entered "3", the command should search for "MovieNumber3, as it's written in the txt file.

Till now everything works, but I need the "selectedmovie" variable to include only the path, and not the text before it. For example, the variable should be "C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Movie1.mp4" and not "MovieNumber1 Path: C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Movie1.mp4". I want to exclude the first 20 characters.

How can I do that?

[Full Code of the Project Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jyCZo94LUpWur8s0Z0LG_jvujW-VF_ABWXZk7KvgHVA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: The HELP for the `SET` command briefly explains substring expansion. This is from the help file: **May also specify substrings for an expansion.    %PATH:~10,5%**. You could in theory also do this with the `TOKENS` and `DELIMS` option of the `FOR` command.

Comment: You described an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You should have asked for help on how to get the full qualified file name from a line containing left to the file name other characters. One solution is `for /F "useback tokens=2*" %%I in ("Movies.txt") do if /I "%%I" == "Path:" echo Movie file is: %%J` You see, it is very easy to get from the text file the data of interest. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help and next run `if /?` and read again the output help to hopefully understand this command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer to this problem.

I simply added `tokens=3*` which selects all characters after ignoring the first 2 words(MovieNumber1 and Path:)

Comment: Your code will fail if there is a space in the file path.

Comment: The command line in my comment above works for `MovieNumber2 Path: C:\Users\danie\Desktop\My Movies\Movie 2.mp4`, but your solution with `tokens=3*` results in processing `C:\Users\danie\Desktop\My` as full qualified file name of the movie file which is not correct.